# Having problems with creating a matrix in Python: Wrong dimension

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am having a problem with creating a matrix. I expect the output matrix d20 to have dimensions nt*12 x ny x nx, but I get a matrix with dimensions nt x ny x nx.

The code (in Python) is as follows:

```
d20=ma.empty([nt*12,ny,nx]); 
 for k in range(nt):
  ee=time[k]
  files3='thetao_ora20c_1m_' +str(ee) +'_grid_1x1.nc'
  fils3 = nc.Dataset(path+ files3,'r')
  t3=np.array(fils3.variables['thetao'][:,:,:,:])  
  for i in range(nx):
   for j in range(ny):
    for monthit in range(12):
     t3c=t3[monthit,:,j,i] 
     dd = [i for (i, val) in enumerate(t3c[:]) if val >= 19.5 and val <= 20.5]
     if len(dd)==0:
      d20[12*k+monthit,j,i]=0;
     else:
      d20[12*k+monthit,j,i]=dep[dd[0]]

CreateFilenc(d20, 'D20', 'meters', lat, lon, path +'D20_global_1900_2009_ora20c_op.nc')
```

Here, for each year, I open a different file. Time is a vector of length nt, in which every element is a year from 1900 to 2009.
Why do I get the wrong dimensions? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Based on the code snippet you provided, the created d20 matrix should have dimensions of nt*12 x ny x nx, as you've expected.

Answer (score 0):

What is "ma"? In case you use numpy, it works:

```
>>> import numpy as np   
>>> nt = 12
>>> nx = 10
>>> ny = 20
>>> d20 = np.empty([nt*12,ny,nx])
>>> print(d20.shape)
(144, 20, 10)
```